# Spring Data Jpa - save OneToMany bidirectional entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm facing a problem with persisting a JPA entity in database.I have a child `Schedule` entity, and a parent `MessageConfig` entity. When calling a `@PostMapping` request with this payload:

```
{
    "emailAdvertisement":{
        "template":"some string",
        "topic": "some string",
        "image": "some string"
    },
    "smsAdvertisement":{
        "text":"smsText"
    },
    "sendTypes":"Sms,Email",
    "schedule":[
        { "timeToSend":"17-04-2023 17:35"},
        { "timeToSend":"17-04-2023 17:45"}
        ]
}
```

I get "Object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing" error. `MessageConfig` is saved in db, but in schedule table the column for message_config_id foreign key is filled with null. My guess is that `Schedule` entity is trying to associate itself with an entity that is not yet persisted.
I've tried following solutions, but still not having a result:

1. Place @CascadeType.All in both sides
2. Place @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE) on ManyToOne side
3. Place @CascadeType.Persist on ManyToOne side

Child entity class

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Schedule {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime timeToSend;


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "config_id")
    private MessageConfig config; //something wrong with this

    private SendStatus sendStatus = SendStatus.WAITING;
}
```

Parent entity class

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MessageConfig {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Customer customer;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
    private EmailAdvertisement emailAdvertisement;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
    private SmsAdvertisement smsAdvertisement;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
    private MessengerAdvertisement messengerAdvertisement;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY,orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Client> clients;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "config", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)  //something wrong with this
    private List<Schedule> schedule;

    private String sendTypes;

    public MessageConfig(EmailAdvertisement emailAdvertisement,
                         SmsAdvertisement smsAdvertisement,
                         MessengerAdvertisement messengerAdvertisement,
                         String sendTypes,
                         List<Client> clients) {
        this.emailAdvertisement = emailAdvertisement;
        this.smsAdvertisement = smsAdvertisement;
        this.messengerAdvertisement = messengerAdvertisement;
        this.sendTypes = sendTypes;
        this.clients = clients;
    }

}
```

Service method to save config in db

```
public ResponseEntity<MessageConfig> postConfig(String configDto, MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            MessageConfig config = mapper.readValue(configDto, MessageConfig.class);
            Customer customer = new Customer("NikePR", "nikePR@gmail.com", "password");
            config.setClients(csvParser.parseCsvToList(file));
            config.setCustomer(customer);
            messageConfigRepository.save(config);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(config, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Is there any solution that will not require additional table with message_config_id/schedule_id mapping

Comment: The entities are correct. Only it will be better to use Set instead of List. And you will need some additional code in the service class. Please share what you have and I can update it.

Comment: @Mar-Z Are you suggesting to assign those child entities manually, and save them after I save MessageConfig entity to db? I've updated this post with service layer method that saves MessageConfig entity to db

Answer (score 0):

The child entities must be saved to the database after the parent entity has been saved. This is because the id of parent will be generated only with the save method.

**Solution** - add following block

```
messageConfigRepository.save(config);

for (Schedule schedule : config.schedule()) {
    schedule.setConfig(config);
    scheduleRepository.save(schedule);
}

return new ResponseEntity<>(config, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```